# How to change the layout of the grading table in the exam document class

Tags: tables, exam

I'm using LuaLaTeX with the exam document class and I would like (if it's possible) to change the default layout of the grading table to be more like the tables from the booktabs package. How can I do that? I read the manual and even if the table command has many options I didn't find a way to do that. I also read a similar question about the exsheet package but the answer provided doesn't compile.

Here is a minimal working example with the tables I'd like to change at the end of it.

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,11pt]{exam} 

\usepackage{fontspec}                    
\usepackage{polyglossia}                          

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question[10]
Example question
\question[20]
Example question
\question[30]
Example question
\question[40]
Example question
\question[50]
Example question
\end{questions}

\begin{center}
\pointtable[v][questions]
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\pointtable[h][questions]
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result

[image]

Comment: I tried to look into the exam.cls file but I don't know how to modify it. Seen as nobody answered I think I'll have to give up and keep the standard layout...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The building of the tables is a little bit tricky in class `exams`.  În my eyes the horizontal table is much more better.

With the following MWE both table are changed. The needed changes you find in the part of the preamble, enclosed with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,11pt]{exam} 

%\usepackage{fontspec}      % No LuaLaTeX !!!!
%\usepackage{polyglossia}   % No LuaLaTeX !!!!
\usepackage{booktabs}


% Change table layout
\makeatletter            % @ a normal letter

%first table:
\def\@vpttblquestions{%
  % Vertical non-bonus point table, indexed by questions:
  \set@hlfcntr{tbl@points}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
%   \hline  % topline
    {\@vqword}& {\@vpword}\\
    \midrule
    \setcounter{question}{\tbl@firstq}%
    \addtocounter{question}{-1}\do@vptloop
    {\@vtword}& \prt@tablepoints\\
%    \hline  % endrule
  \end{tabular}%
}% @vpttblquestions
\def\do@vptloop{%
  % \do@vptloop is used by \@vpttblquestions
  \addtocounter{question}{1}%
  \ref{question@\arabic{question}} &
        \pointsofquestion{\arabic{question}}\\
%  \hline
  \@ifundefined{pointsofq@\romannumeral \c@question}%
    {}%
    {\addto@hlfcntr{tbl@points}
       {\csname pointsofq@\romannumeral \c@question\endcsname}}%
  \ifnum \value{question} < \tbl@lastq\relax
    \let\next@vptloop=\do@vptloop
  \else
    \let\next@vptloop=\relax
  \fi
  \next@vptloop
}% do@vptloop

% second table
\def\@htblquestions{%
  % We get here from \@tblquestions.
  % The table is horizontal and indexed by question numbers.
  % The question range has already been determined.
  % Set num@cols equal to the number of questions on the table, and
  % do either bonus, combined, or non-bonus table, in each case
  % putting in a line for scores only if it's a gradetable:
  \@ifundefined{exam@numquestions}%
  {}%
  {%
    \setcounter{num@cols}{\tbl@lastq}%
    \addtocounter{num@cols}{-\tbl@firstq}%
    \addtocounter{num@cols}{1}%
  }%
  % Do either bonus, combined, or non-bonus table.  In each case, put
  % in a line for scores if it's a gradetable:
  \begingroup
    % Save the current value of question in @iterator, so that
    % we can restore it after doing the table:
    \setcounter{@iterator}{\value{question}}%
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{\@gtblstretch}%
    \if@bonus
      % It's a horizontal bonus table, by questions:
      \begin{tabular}{l*{\thenum@cols}{c}c}
%        \hline
        {\@bhqword}& \setcounter{question}{\tbl@firstq}%
        \addtocounter{question}{-1}\do@qnumloop
        {\@bhtword}\\
%        \hline
        \set@hlfcntr{tbl@bonuspoints}{0}%
        {\@bhpword}& \setcounter{question}{\tbl@firstq}%
        \addtocounter{question}{-1}\do@bptloop
        \prt@tablebonuspoints\\
%        \hline
        % If it's a grade table, add in the score line:
        \if@scores
          {\@bhsword}& \setcounter{question}{\tbl@firstq}%
          \addtocounter{question}{-1}\do@sloop
          \\
%          \hline
        \fi
      \end{tabular}%
    \else
      \if@combined
        % It's a horizontal combined table, by questions:
        \begin{tabular}{l*{\thenum@cols}{c}c}
%          \hline
          {\@chqword}& \setcounter{question}{\tbl@firstq}%
          \addtocounter{question}{-1}\do@qnumloop
          {\@chtword}\\
%          \hline
          \set@hlfcntr{tbl@points}{0}%
          {\@chpword}& \setcounter{question}{\tbl@firstq}%
          \addtocounter{question}{-1}\do@ptloop
          \prt@tablepoints\\
%          \hline
          \set@hlfcntr{tbl@bonuspoints}{0}%
          {\@chbpword}& \setcounter{question}{\tbl@firstq}%
          \addtocounter{question}{-1}\do@bptloop
          \prt@tablebonuspoints\\
%          \hline
          % If it's a grade table, add in the score line:
          \if@scores
            {\@chsword}& \setcounter{question}{\tbl@firstq}%
            \addtocounter{question}{-1}\do@sloop
            \\
%            \hline
          \fi
        \end{tabular}%
      \else
        % Horizontal non-bonus table, indexed by question number:
        \set@hlfcntr{tbl@points}{0}%
        \begin{tabular}{l*{\thenum@cols}{c}c}
%          \hline
          {\@hqword}& \setcounter{question}{\tbl@firstq}%
          \addtocounter{question}{-1}\do@qnumloop
          {\@htword}\\
          \midrule
          {\@hpword}& \setcounter{question}{\tbl@firstq}%
          \addtocounter{question}{-1}\do@ptloop
          \prt@tablepoints\\
%          \hline
          % If it's a grade table, add in the score line:
          \if@scores
            {\@hsword}& \setcounter{question}{\tbl@firstq}%
            \addtocounter{question}{-1}\do@sloop
            \\
%            \hline
          \fi
        \end{tabular}%
      \fi
    \fi
    % Restore the saved value of question:
    \setcounter{question}{\value{@iterator}}%
  \endgroup
}% @htblquestions

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question[10]
Example question
\question[20]
Example question
\question[30]
Example question
\question[40]
Example question
\question[50]
Example question
\end{questions}

\begin{center}
\pointtable[v][questions]
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\pointtable[h][questions]
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

With the result:

[image]

It would be better if the author of the class would integrate two different layouts for the tables in his class.

Comment: How can I change the language in Italian? thanks a lot! ;)

Comment: @ryuk it depends if you compile with pdflatex or lualatex or other. For `pdflatex` use package `babel`.

Comment: @Mensch , how could you change the columns order? thanks in advance

Comment: @MamounMohammed Please ask a new question and explain better what you mean with "change the colums order" ...

Comment: When I am compiling your code (either pdfLaTeX or with LuaLaTeX), I do not get the result you have – I have the same tables as usual (i.e. unchanged). How is that possible?

Comment: Your answer is really close to what I need to be done in my question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/622217/2288. So, I hope if you could take a look at it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you please check if your answer is working now or not? As it doesn't get the desired output with me for the most recent version of exam.