# Generate a grading table for exam using tabularray

Tags: tables, exam, tabularray

I would like to have two commands that automate the generation of both vertical and horizontal grading tables to look the same as those manually written by me below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,11pt]{exam} 

\marksnotpoints

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\vqword{Question}
\vpword{Marks}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{coverpages}
        
    \begin{tblr}
        [
        presep = 0pt, headsep = 0pt,
        footsep = 0pt, postsep = 0pt,
        ]{
            colsep = 1 em,
            column{1} = {0.15\linewidth},
            width = 0.5\linewidth,
            colspec = {
                X[ c, 2 ]
                X[ c, 1.5 ]
                X[ c, 1.5 ]
            },
            hline{2-Z} = {0.25pt},
            vlines = {0.25pt},
            rows = {m},
            row{1} = {10ex, font = \bfseries},
            row{2-Z} = {6ex, m},
            row{Z} = {font = \bfseries},
            rulesep = 0pt,
            rowsep = 0ex,
        }
        \toprule[1.5pt]
        Question & Marks & Score \\
        1\textsuperscript{st} & 10 & \\
        2\textsuperscript{nd} & 20 & \\
        3\textsuperscript{rd} & 30 & \\
        Total & 60 & \\
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]
    \end{tblr}
    
    \bigskip
    
    \begin{tblr}
        [
        presep = 0pt, headsep = 0pt,
        footsep = 0pt, postsep = 0pt,
        ]{
            colsep = 1 em,
            column{1} = {0.15\linewidth, font = \bfseries},
            column{Z} = {font = \bfseries},
            width = 0.75\linewidth,
            colspec = {
                X[ l, 2 ]
                *{3}{X[ c, 1.5 ]}
                X[ c, 2 ]
            },
            hline{2-Z} = {0.25pt},
            vlines = {0.25pt},
            rows = {6ex, m},
            rulesep = 0pt,
            rowsep = 0ex,
        }
        \toprule[1.5pt]
        Question & 1\textsuperscript{st} & 2\textsuperscript{nd} & 3\textsuperscript{rd} & Total \\
        Marks & 10 & 20 & 30 & 60\\
        Score &  &  &  & \\
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]
    \end{tblr}

    \end{coverpages}

    \begin{questions}
        \question[10]
        Example question
        \question[20]
        Example question
        \question[30]
        Example question
    \end{questions}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: @JohnKormylo I totally overlooked it. Sorry for that. Done

Comment: The numbers are available from the aux file using `\csname pointsofq@i\endcsname` etc and `\csname exam@numpoints\endcsname`.  Creating a table with a vaiaible number of rows or columns might be trickier.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the built-in `\gradetable` command from the `exam` class.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,11pt]{exam} 
\marksnotpoints
\vpword{Marks}
\hpword{Marks:}%<--
\begin{document}
\begin{coverpages}

\begin{center}
\gradetable[h][questions]%<--
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\gradetable[v][questions]%<--
\end{center}

\end{coverpages}
\begin{questions}
        \question[10]
        Example question
        \question[20]
        Example question
        \question[30]
        Example question
\end{questions}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know the existence of such an option; I would like to be able to customize the generation the way I want.

Comment: @Diaa Do you want to format it?

Comment: @JasperHabicht if you are talking about the built-in one, then yes. However, I am not a TeXpert to manipulate things under the hood, so I wondered if I could create my own one using tabularray.

Answer (score 1):

This is as far as I got.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,11pt]{exam} 

\marksnotpoints

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\vqword{Question}
\vpword{Marks}

\begin{document}

    \begin{coverpages}
        
        
    \begin{tblr}
        [
        presep = 0pt, headsep = 0pt,
        footsep = 0pt, postsep = 0pt,
        ]{
            colsep = 1 em,
            column{1} = {0.15\linewidth},
            width = 0.5\linewidth,
            colspec = {
                X[ c, 2 ]
                X[ c, 1.5 ]
                X[ c, 1.5 ]
            },
            hline{2-Z} = {0.25pt},
            vlines = {0.25pt},
            rows = {m},
            row{1} = {10ex, font = \bfseries},
            row{2-Z} = {6ex, m},
            row{Z} = {font = \bfseries},
            rulesep = 0pt,
            rowsep = 0ex,
        }
        \toprule[1.5pt]
        Question & Marks & Score \\
        1\textsuperscript{st} & {\csname pointsofq@i\endcsname} & \\
        2\textsuperscript{nd} & {\csname pointsofq@ii\endcsname} & \\
        3\textsuperscript{rd} & {\csname pointsofq@iii\endcsname} & \\
        Total & {\csname exam@numpoints\endcsname} & \\
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]
    \end{tblr}
    
    \bigskip
    
    
    \begin{tblr}
        [
        presep = 0pt, headsep = 0pt,
        footsep = 0pt, postsep = 0pt,
        ]{
            colsep = 1 em,
            column{1} = {0.15\linewidth, font = \bfseries},
            column{Z} = {font = \bfseries},
            width = 0.75\linewidth,
            colspec = {
                X[ l, 2 ]
                *{3}{X[ c, 1.5 ]}
                X[ c, 2 ]
            },
            hline{2-Z} = {0.25pt},
            vlines = {0.25pt},
            rows = {6ex, m},
            rulesep = 0pt,
            rowsep = 0ex,
        }
        \toprule[1.5pt]
        Question & 1\textsuperscript{st} & 2\textsuperscript{nd} & 3\textsuperscript{rd} & Total \\
        Marks & {\csname pointsofq@i\endcsname} & {\csname pointsofq@ii\endcsname} & {\csname pointsofq@iii\endcsname} & {\csname exam@numpoints\endcsname}\\
        Score &  &  &  & \\
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]
    \end{tblr}

    \end{coverpages}
    
    
    
    \begin{questions}
        \question[10]
        Example question
        \question[20]
        Example question
        \question[30]
        Example question
    \end{questions}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a for loop over the total number of questions to robustly print a row for each question?

Comment: I think a for loop over `\numquestions` is what remains to make your answer completely robust with a question counter to convert it to its ordinal.